# Using MPI_Type_create_subarray for passing around 3D arrays

Tags: c, mpi

```
double*** esfld;

void allocate()
{ //... malloced all three dimensions of the esfld 3D array }

void initialize()
{ //... Initialize every element in all three dimensions of esfld to zero}

MPI_Datatype make3dtype()
{
    int array_of_sizes[]={nz,ny,nx};
    int array_of_subsizes[]={nz,ny,nx};
    int array_of_starts[]={0,0,0};
    MPI_Datatype arr3d;
    int ndims=3;
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(ndims,array_of_sizes,array_of_subsizes,array_of_starts,MPI_ORDER_C,MPI_DOUBLE,&arr3d);
    MPI_Type_commit(&arr3d);
    return arr3d;
}

void sendData()
{
    MPI_Datatype arr3d=make3dtype();
    MPI_Type_commit(&arr3d);
    MPI_Send(esfld,1,arr3d,1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void receiveData()
{  
   MPI_Status status;
   MPI_Datatype arr3d=make3dtype();
   MPI_Type_commit(&arr3d);
   MPI_Recv(esfld,1,arr3d,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

}

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    allocate();
    initialize();

    int size,rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(rank==0){
            sendData();
        }
        else if(rank==1){
            receiveData();
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Get a segfault because of this code.
The segfaults are not in the allocation or initialization functions, I've tried that. 
Its the sending/receiving of arr3d types that is causing this.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you're sending the whole array, you don't need `MPI_Type_create_subarray()` - you can just send `nx*ny*nz` `MPI_DOUBLE`s starting at `arr3d[0][0][0]`.  That doesn't explain the segfault, though; what does your `allocate()` look like?

Comment: @JonathanDursi This is no longer a problem actually, I used your allocate3d() method from another answer and the segfault is gone. Are you saying that I can send a 3d array just like I would send a 1d array ?

Comment: Yes; once the data is contiguous in memory, you can just send `nx*ny*nz` `MPI_DOUBLE`s starting at `arr3d[0][0][0]`.  There's nothing wrong with using an array type, but that's really to pick out non-contiguous sub regions of the whole array - and as you've seen, it alone can't help you if the underlying 3d array isn't contiguous.